# How to do login using MVVM?

Tags: swift, dictionary, mvvm, nsdictionary, completionhandler

I am still quite new to iOS development and I am trying to teach myself good coding practices and design patterns in Swift starting with MVVM. I need to pass the data from a completion handle in my ServiceCall class to my ViewModel. I would like assistance in understanding how I can do it and also guidance in best practices using MVVM on my code.

This is what I have done so far:

**Model**

```
struct Login {
  var appVersion: String ?
  var deviceID : String ?
  var deviceOS : String ?
  var password : String ?
  var username : String ?
}
```

**Service Call / API Client**

```
class LoginServiceCall : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
  let viewResponse = ThrowResponse()
  func requestLogin(request: URLRequest, requestObject: Login, completion: @escaping ([NSDictionary] ? ) -> Void) {
    let searchParams = Login.init(appVersion: requestObject.appVersion, deviceID: requestObject.deviceID, deviceOS: requestObject.deviceOS, password: requestObject.password, username: requestObject.username)
    var request = request
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    do {
      request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: searchParams, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
      data, response, error -> Void in
      do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as ? Dictionary<String, Any>
        //completion(json!)
        // This is where i would like to pass the dictionary data
      } catch {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.viewResponse.dismissLoader()
          self.viewResponse.showFailureAlert(title: "Failure", message: "")
          completion(nil)
        }
      }
    })
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

**View Controller**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var loginButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var usernameOrEmailTextField: UITextField ?
  @IBOutlet var passwordTextField : UITextField ?
  var serviceBalance = 0.0
  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  var Reach : Reachability ? = Reachability()
  var viewModel : LoginViewModel ?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    usernameOrEmailTextField?.delegate = self
    passwordTextField?.delegate = self
  }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    usernameOrEmailTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
    return (true)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    viewModel?.setLoginObject(withUsername: usernameOrEmailTextField?.text, withPassword : passwordTextField?.text)
  }

  @IBAction func forgotPasswordButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "forgotPasswordSegue", sender: nil)
  }

  @IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerUserSegue", sender: nil)
  }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel: NSObject {

    var Reach: Reachability? = Reachability()
    var login: Login?
    var homeViewDictionary: [NSDictionary]?
    var APIClient: LoginServiceCall!
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myapiuser/login")!)

    func setLoginObject(withUsername username: String?, withPassword password: String?){
        login?.username = username
        login?.password = password
        login?.appVersion = self.getAppVersion()
        login?.deviceID = self.getDeviceID()
        login?.deviceOS = self.getDeviceOs()

        APIClient.requestLogin(request: request, requestObject: login! { (AppDictionary) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.homeViewDictionary = AppDictionary
            }
        }, completion: ())
    }

    func getAppVersion() -> String { return "0.2" }

    func getDeviceID() -> String {
        if let deviceid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString { return deviceid }
    }

    func getDeviceOs() -> String {
        let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
        let model = UIDevice.current.model
        return systemVersion+" "+model
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Just to be clear, you want to apply MVVM pattern on this code that is not MVVM yet? I may be a bit lost because I don't know swift but only basic c#/WPF/MVVM terminology, but this controller is still using code behind right? Not MVVM. A login form using MVVM seems something easy to find in tutorials, even if not using swift it will be a good start anyway to understand the pattern.

Comment: @erent have you find any good method for your question?